# Selecting the difference between dates in a stored procedure using a subquery

Tags: sql, datetime, subquery, inner-join, window-functions

I can't get my head around whether this is even possible, but I feel like I might have done it before and lost that bit of code.  I am trying to craft a select statement that contains an inner join on a subquery to show the number of days between two dates from the same table.

A simple example of the data structure would look like:

```
Name  ID  Date    Day       Hours
Bill  1   3/3/20  Thursday   8
Fred  2   4/3/20  Monday     6
Bill  1   8/3/20  Tuesday    2
```

Based on this data, I want to select each row plus an extra column which is the number of days between the date from each row for each ID.  Something like:

```
Select * from tblData
Inner join (datediff(Select Top(1) Date from tblData where Date < Date), Date) And ID = ID)
```

or for simplicity:

```
Select * from tblData
Inner join (datediff(Select Top(1) Date from tblData where Date < 8/3/20), 8/3/20) And ID = 1)
```

The resulting dataset would look like:

```
Name  ID  Date    Day       Hours  DaysBtwn
Bill  1   3/3/20  Thursday   8     4 (Assuming there was an earlier row in the table)
Fred  2   4/3/20  Monday     6     5 (Assuming there was an earlier row in the table)
Bill  1   8/3/20  Tuesday    2     5 (Based on the previous row date being 3/3/20 for Bill)
```

Does this make sense and am I trying to do this the wrong way?  I want to do this for about 600000 rows in table and therefore efficiency is the key, so if there is a better way to do this, i'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*, datediff(day, lag(date) over(partition by id order by date), date) diff
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(day,
                lag(date) over (partition by name order by date),
                date
               ) as diff
from tblData t;
```

Note:  If you want to filter the data so rows in the result set are used for the `lag()` but not in the result set, then use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             datediff(day,
                      lag(date) over (partition by name order by date),
                      date
                     ) as diff
      from tblData t
     ) t
where date < '2020-08-03';
```

Also note the use of the date constant as a string in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.  Thank you so much!